# How to send a selected element and a text input via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

My app has a live search implemented and it works properly. The problem that I have is that now I have a table with a lot of columns and I want to search through all elements. I want to have only one text input and a drop down that will select the column that I want to search in.

**Searchable module**

```
module Searchable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def search_for(present_column,record)
      record.present? ? where(present_column+' LIKE ?', record+"%") : all
    end
  end
end
```

**People controller**

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @people = Person.page(params[:page]).per(5).search_for(params[:object_columns], params[:search])
  end
```

**The search engine**

```
<%= form_tag do %>
  <% valid_column_names = target.column_names.reject{|r| r == "created_at" || r == "updated_at" || r == "slug"} %>
  <%= select_tag :object_columns, options_for_select(valid_column_names) %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, '', autocomplete: :off %>
<% end %>
```

**The live search js**

```
$(function () {
    $("input#search").keyup(function () {
        $.get($("#object_columns option:selected").text(), $("#object_columns").serialize(), null, "script");
        $.get($("#search").attr("action"), $("#search").serialize(), null, "script");
    });
});
```

The input text is returned as expected, but nothing comes from the *object_columns*. When I type the word "n", for example, my server terminal returns this message:

```
Started GET "/people?&search=n&_=1463081307356" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-05-12 16:28:34 -0300
Processing by PeopleController#index as JS
  Parameters: {"search"=>"n", "_"=>"1463081307356"}
```

**EDIT:**

I had an idea later on and made some changes. I gave the form an ID and used it to do the request, now I can have both information (column names and the search record) at the same time. The only problem now is with the path, it is returning an URI error.

**The search engine**

```
<%= form_tag people_path, class: "form_id" do %>
  <% valid_column_names = target.column_names.reject{|r| r == "created_at" || r == "updated_at" || r == "slug"} %>
  <%= select_tag :object_columns, options_for_select(valid_column_names) %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, '', autocomplete: :off %>
<% end %>
```

**The live search**

```
$(function () {
    $("input#search").keyup(function () {
        $.get($(".form_id"), $(".form_id").serialize(), null, "script");null, "script");
    });
});
```

Comment: not quite understood `def search_for(present_column,record)` method, what the return value is `all` for?

Comment: You are doing two `$.get` (GET) requests to your server. could you comment the line where you send $('#search')? Do you see a GET request to the server?

Comment: Sorry, the "all" was a test, it was removed from the real code and I forgot to remove from here, without it, doesn't work either

Comment: @Leito when I removed the $('#search') request, the column names returned like this:

`Started GET "/name?object_columns=name&_=1463142917053" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-05-13 09:35:22 -0300`

Comment: So, now I can get the column name and the search field, but not together, only one at a time, how do I get both of them at the same time when a key is pressed?

Comment: I made some changes and I did it, I can have both information now. My only problem now is the path that is not working...

Comment: If you get both, please update your question to reflect the new data, logs, etc. To send both you probably want to [serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) the form.

Comment: It's already done under the EDIT section...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `search_for` method, the return value is always `all`.  You really want the return value to be the result of the ternary operator directly above it.  Remove the last `all` and you should be good to go.

```
module ClassMethods
  def search_for(present_column,record)
    record.present? ? where(present_column+' LIKE ?', record+"%") : all
    # all  <== this should be removed
  end
end
```

In your javascript, you'll need a few changes:

```
$(function () {
    function search() {
        $.get("/search", { column_name: $("select#column_name").val(), search: $("#search").val() }, null, "script");
    };

    $("select#column_name").change(search); 
    $("input#search").keyup(search);
});
```

The actual Ajax call has been changed to:

- remove the undefined "action" attribute on the search input field
- explicitly reference the URL to send the request
- create hash parameters for the ajax call
- remove the unnecessary calls to `serialize()`

This also installs a handler on the `change` event of the column selection, hence the refactoring of the Ajax call to a separate function.

Comment: Sorry, the "all" was a test, it was removed from the real code and I forgot to remove from here, without it, doesn't work either...

Comment: @RaventheBard I updated the javascript code, so you might want to try it.  I was able to get it to work correctly in my test application.